# Version control: Create tags afterwards

Tags: svn, version-control, tags

How can I create a svn tag afterwards?

I have changed the repository structure to fit to the normal trunk, tags and braches structure. How can I now create tags for old revisions?

Curriently I'm tring this:

```
svn copy dev/somedir@35 tags/Stable-1.0 -r 35
```

But I get this error:

> svn: E155010: The node '/path/to/repo/dev/somedir' was not found.

This is normal for the currient state but not true for the revision 35.

How can I fix this problem? Should I check out the old rev 35 and copy the content to the currient version? Or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to repeat your question: The path `/dev/somedir` exists in rev 35, in between the directory structure changed, the path `/dev/somedir` does not exist in the HEAD revision, and the path `/tags` does not exist in rev 35. You want to copy `/dev/somedir` from rev 35 to `/tags`. Correct?

Try the following command:

```
svn cp ^/dev/somedir@35 ^/tags/Stable-1.0
```

This command works with two URLs instead of paths in the working copy. I strongly recommend the usage of URLs when creating tags and branches.

The following operation should work as well (combination of URL and WC). However, I strongly advise against using it:

```
svn cp ^/dev/somedir@35 tags/Stable-1.0
```